# Unusual approach to assess a predictive model's performance?

Tags: predictive-models, scoring-rules

Context: I am working on a predictive model. Let's call it $f$. The outcome that $f$ is trying to predict is binary. It makes predictions as probabilities, i.e. for a given input $x$, $f(x) \in (0,1)$. Its performance seems to be so-so: The AUC is 0.67 and the average precision is 0.73 (compared to 58% positive cases in the test set).

I was pondering the merits of the model when I came up with this approach at assessing the model's performance that (I think/hope) takes noise and inherent uncertainty in the data into account:

[image: grouped predicted probability against proportion of positive cases]

I'll explain this table by explaining what the row with index (0.2, 0.3] says: Of the model's predictions on the test set, 30 predictions were between 0.2 and 0.3. Of these 30 points, 5 were positive (outcome = 1). The proportion 0.1667 is 5 divided by 30.

The idea behind this approach is frequentist in nature: If the model makes predictions of 0.25 for a number of points, then 25% of these points should have a positive outcome. Likewise for other probabilities. In this particular case the proportion does indeed lie in the given range for most of the rows. So I guess the model is actually okay?

I have tried to find this approach somewhere in the literature, but it's hard to know which keywords to use (see question 2 below).

My question is:

1. Is this a meaningful approach?

If it is a meaningful approach, then two more questions:

2. Does it have a name?
3. Is it really just the ROC curve, the precision–recall curve or even the log loss in (discrete) disguise?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you plot the binned proportions of positive cases against the bins, you get a *reliability diagram*. We have a [reliability](/questions/tagged/reliability) tag which is not really helpful in this case, and [a number of relevant threads](https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=reliability+diagram). [Dimitriadis et al. (2021)](https://doi.org/10.1073/pnas.2016191118) is a recent treatment.